# Broadcast Receiver for receiving SMS not working

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, sms

I'd like to made an mobile application to do things after SMS is reveived.
I made an interface of the "SMS-Class" that defines all methods.
Then I made a Class in the Main Xamarin Forms project witch inherit from the interface (this way I can't miss to create any method).
Next I created a class in the Android part of the project witch should read (and more) SMS on receiving.

I called the mehtod of the android part with DependencyService from the class in the main project.

To manage the incomming SMS in android I did the following:
I made a method (in the Android project - "CheckForIncommingSMS") to register a BroadcastReceiver witch should be the calling class itself.
The mentioned method is called from the MainPage in the main project.
MainPage => SMSHelper.CheckForIncommingSMS() => Android Project => registring BroadcastReceiver for incomming SMS
Screenmessage when SMS received.

The Broadcast Receiver itself seems to work.
I tested it with other intentactions and it worked.

I found out that the OnReceive-method isn't called.

What did I wrong?

Thanks!

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using App.Models;

namespace App.Services
{
    public interface ISMSHelper
    {
        void CheckForIncommingSMS();
        void Create(string sender, string receiver, string message);
        void Send();
        List<SMS> ReadAll();
        SMS Get();
    }
}


using System.Collections.Generic;
using App.Models;
using Xamarin.Forms;

// Class in Main Xamarin Forms Project

[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(App.Services.SMSHelper))]
namespace App.Services
{
    class SMSHelper : ISMSHelper
    {
        public void CheckForIncommingSMS()
        {
            DependencyService.Get<ISMSHelper>().CheckForIncommingSMS();
        }

        public void Create(string sender, string receiver, string message)
        {
            DependencyService.Get<ISMSHelper>().Create(sender, receiver, message);

        }

        public SMS Get()
        {
            return DependencyService.Get<ISMSHelper>().Get();
        }

        public List<SMS> ReadAll()
        {
            return DependencyService.Get<ISMSHelper>().ReadAll();
        }

        public void Send()
        {
            DependencyService.Get<ISMSHelper>().Send();
        }
    }
}


//Class in Xamarin Forms Project (Android)

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Provider;
using Android.Telephony;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Widget;
using Plugin.Messaging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using App.Models;
using App.Services;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(App.Droid.SMSHelper))]
namespace App.Droid
{
    [BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Label = "SMS Receiver")]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" })]
    public class SMSHelper : BroadcastReceiver, ISMSHelper
    {
        private const string Tag = "SMSBroadcastReceiver";
        private const string IntentAction = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

        SMS sms = new SMS();

        public SMSHelper() {
            /* https://blog.xamarin.com/cross-platform-messaging-for-ios-android-and-windows https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/13682/broadcastreceiver-for-sms*/}

        public void Create(string sender, string receiver, string message)
        {
            sms.Sender = sender;
            sms.Receiver = receiver;
            sms.Message = message;
        }

        public void Send()
        {
            if ((!sms.Receiver.Equals("")) && (!sms.Message.Equals("")))
            {
                var smsMessenger = CrossMessaging.Current.SmsMessenger;

                if (smsMessenger.CanSendSmsInBackground)
                {
                    smsMessenger.SendSmsInBackground(sms.Receiver, sms.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        public SMS Get()
        {
            return sms;
        }

        public List<SMS> ReadAll()
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            Log.Info(Tag, "Intent received: " + intent.Action);


            if (intent.Action != IntentAction) return;

            SmsMessage[] messages = Telephony.Sms.Intents.GetMessagesFromIntent(intent);

            for (var i = 0; i < messages.Length; i++)
            {
                sms.Sender = messages[i].OriginatingAddress;
                sms.Message = messages[i].MessageBody;
                sms.Timestamp = DateTime.Now;

                Toast.MakeText(context, sms.Message, ToastLength.Long).Show();
                Debug.WriteLine("SMS ER");
            }

            Toast.MakeText(context, "sdfghhj", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }

        public void CheckForIncommingSMS()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("HALLO");
            Forms.Context.RegisterReceiver(this, new IntentFilter(IntentAction));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you request related permission in your Android project? Also, please note that  when API >= 23, [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html?hl=en-us), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app.

Comment: I forgot to ask for permissions at runtime. Thanks!